# SQL Server : index not fragmented but query became slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

In the production environment where I work there's a very odd problem.

We got a simple query that is running very often, and without any problem. A `DBCC DBREINDEX(..)` of the table is planned every night at 01.30 am, and usually everything is fine.

But once every one or two weeks, the query became slow and all users can't work. This happen early in the morning (9.00 am) so right next the index rebuild.

When this happen I do a reindex of two indexes of the table and all came back to normality for another week.

If I check the index stats when that slowdown happens everything is fine, fragmentation is about at 0.2

If I check the estimated execution plan PRE and AFTER the issue I see no changes.

The query is very simple:

```
SELECT SUM(A.QTY) 
FROM WMSORDER A 
WHERE ((DATAAREAID = '01') AND (INVENTTRANSID = '046830648'))
```

and there is and index on the columns `DATAAREAID` and `INVENTTRANSID`

Here I post two images with the index stats where the issue occurs:

[PRE REINDEX STATISTICS WITH SLOW PERFORMANCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYk7P.jpg)

[EXECUTION PLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s49pQ.jpg)

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: The fragmentation is `0.2` or `0.2 %`? That's quite a big difference :) Also, are you sure the database actually finished rebuilding the indices? It might very well be that the maintenance operations are still executing.

Comment: It could be parameter sniffing. Read this excellent article by Erland Sommarskog [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) Get the **actual** execution plan when it runs fast and when it runs slow. Most likely there will be a difference.

Comment: You are right, it was a problem of Parameter Sniffing.. Solved it with an hotfix for the software I was using (Dynamics AX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of parameter sniffing.

I solved forcing literals in the DATAAREAID parameters instead of using the @parameter.

Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

The index you are using is not the best one for that query. The execution plan includes a KeyLookup to get the qty. I suggest you to drop that index and create the following covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_WMSORDER_INVENTTRANSID_DATAAREAID 
ON WMSORDER(NVENTTRANSID, DATAAREAID)
INCLUDE (QTY)
```

Comment: I know that including the qty would be better, but the index is a standard index that I cannot change.
Moreover, this index is used frequently in other areas of the system that don't need the qty to be indexed.
What I really need to know is why sometimes the query start slowing down even if the indexes are not fragmented!